# Joining 3 tables in Hive - ParseException extraneous input '_SYNTHJOIN_expecting ) near '<EOF>'

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I want to join 3 tables,

summary

```
dept_cd | call_dt |  cust_id | hold_time | talk_time |  work_time | call_cd
```

calls

```
cust_id | call_count | agent_length
```

category

```
cust_id | call_type |  call_category |  call_start_dt | agent_cd | agent_cd
```

this is what I want in the output table,

## output

```
call_date |sum(talk_time)| sum(work_time)| sum(hold_time)| dept_cd| sum(call_count)| call_type|call_category| call_start_date
```

The code is working if I join only summary and call tables, when I add the third table I am receiving parseexception errors

this is my code,

```
select
    SU.call_dt,
    SU.dep_code,
    CG.call_type,
    CG.call_category,
    CG.call_start_dt,
    sum(SU.hold_time) as sum_hold,
    sum(SU.talk_time) as sum_talk,
    sum(SU.work_time) as sum_work,
    sum(CA.call_count)as sum_calls
from summary SU
    inner join 
        (select distinct cust_id, call_count from calls) CA on SU.cust_id = CA.cust_id
    inner join 
        (select call_type,call_category,cust_id,call_start_dt from category) CG on SU.cust_id = CG.cust_id
where 
    CG.call_start_dt between '2019-07-01' and '2019-07-31'
    and SU.call_dt between '2019-07-01' and '2019-07-31'
group by
    SU.call_dt,
    SU.dep_code,
    CG.call_type,
    CG.call_category,
    CG.call_start_dt;
```

Am receiving the below error for the columns where 'SUM' is used..

Error while compiling statement:

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:808 extraneous input '_SYNTHJOIN_4324cda7___Stalk_time_' expecting ) near ''
>   line 1:918 extraneous input '_SYNTHJOIN_4324cda7___Shold_time_' expecting ) near ''
>   line 1:1028 extraneous input '_SYNTHJOIN_4324cda7___Swork_time_' expecting ) near ''

How can I fix this ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks forpas. That was a typo. Edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a need for a subquery.  Does this do what you want?

```
from summary SU inner join 
     (select distinct cust_id, call_count
      from calls
     ) CA
     on SU.cust_id = CA.cust_id inner join 
     from category CG
     on SU.cust_id = CG.cust_id
```

A column called `cust_id` in a table called `category` is suspicious.  I would expect the `join` to be more on something like `category_id`.

Comment: Thank you,Gordon. Looks like I made a mistake while adding the question, There are like 100 columns in summary tables and I want only 4 columns from that table(I just edited to add few more columns in 3 tables which are not used in the query). Also, I have to sum certain colums like talk_time_work_time_hold_time. So doesn't it need group_by ?

Comment: @vamsi115 . . . This answer only addresses the `from` clause.  Of course a query needs a `SELECT` and an aggregation query a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Understood, thanks. I tried it, removed the sub query but received the same error. Also, tried to join on cal_dt instead of cust_id but the result is same. Am receiving the error for the columns in summary table for which I used SUM.